# If $A^{4}=I$, does this imply $A$ is invertible?

Tags: matrices

If I have an $n\times n$ matrix, and $A^{4}=I_n$, does this imply that $A^{-1}$ exists?

My reasoning is

$A^{4}=I$, so $(A^{4})^{-1}=I=(A^{-1})^{4}$.

Is this valid? Thanks for your time in answering what is probably a super simple question.

Comment: Not correct: You already **assume** that $A$ has an inverse. It is much simpler: You can give a $B$ with $AB=I$.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the reasoning was bad.

Comment: Your reasoning doesn't imply the existence of $A^{-1}$. In order to write an equation like $(A^{-1})^4=I$ you have to make sure $A^{-1}$ exists (see the answers below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reasoning is not correct. You claim that $(A^4)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^4$, but you don't know that yet because you don't know that $A^{-1}$ even exists.

You need to **prove** that $A^{-1}$ exists. You prove that by proving that there exists some matrix $B$ such that $AB=BA=I$.

Comment: Thanks! I had a suspicion this was the case.

Answer (score 12):

The equation $A^4=I$ says precisely that $A^{-1}=A^3$.

Comment: I don't think "choose" is the right word since we can't really choose an inverse.  It either exists and is unique or it doesn't exist at all.  But +1 for the concise and correct answer.

Comment: This is indeed true, but i couldn't think of a proper term instead of "choose". I'll edit my post in order to get that clear.

Comment: @Janik I've suggested an alternative wording.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you, I was a few seconds too late to do it myself.

Comment: I knew this going in, but wanted to check the logic of the reasoning I provided above. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 7):

Take the determinant of $A^4$:
$$[\det(A)]^4=\det(A^4)=\det(I_n)=1$$
so $\det(A)\not=0$ and $A$ is invertible.

Aternative approach: let $M:=A^3$ then $A\cdot M=M\cdot A=A^4=I_n$ which implies by definition that $A$ is invertible and its inverse is $M$.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense.

Comment: You're using a not quite trivial theorem here - in fact the result is trivial from the _definition_...

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$ for $n \geq 1$. This rules out the possibility of zero eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

A^4=I 
➡ A^(-1)=A^3. We can write it but we can write it when inverse exists. We shall first know that the inverse is exist or not.